# Weight paint by mesh element (For Hard Surface Meshes)?

Tags: rigging, weight-painting

I'm brand new to Blender - like today is my first day using it. I've used 3DSMax for 22 years though. Loving blender so far, but I'm rigging a mech (hard surface) and I'm getting a bit frustrated with the weight painting. In Max there's an option for me to simply select the elements of the mesh and assign 100% weight strength to a single bone. This is super helpful when rigging a hard surface model. In Blender though I can't for the life of me find a tutorial that shows how to do this. I tried switching to edit mode on my mesh, hiding everything but the element that I want to affect, but as soon as I switch back to Weight Paint, all of the hidden geometry re-appears which means the painting is affecting parts of the model I don't want it to.

Here's an example of me doing this in 3DS Max: https://youtu.be/4vn97_HywZg

Anyone know how to do this in Blender?

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In edit mode, under vertex group properties, you can directly assign weight, without the need of weight painting.

If you select some vertices in edit mode, then switch to weight paint mode, you can enable the Face or vertex selection mask, to affect only selected.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Thanks Josh! I think I'll be able to figure out how to do this :) The pictures are well appreciated!